# bitmap data as movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata, assets

I import my images with

imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
imageLoader.load(imageRequest);

and then try and cast as a movieclip:

var newImage:MovieClip = imageLoader.content as MovieClip;
addChild(newImage);

i keep getting errors, is this possible?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 1):

Don't cast it as a MovieClip. Just add the loader to the stage, like this:

```
addChild(imageLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only do that when the loader has completed loading.

so if that bit of code is in the onComplete function, and you're doing `var newImage:MovieClip = e.content as MovieClip;`, that should work.

What specific errors are you getting?